# Jackson's Access.WRITE_ONLY during test null

Tags: java, rest, testing, spring-boot, jackson

I'm currently playing around with Jackson's de/serialization features and I encountered a problem, I don't know how to solve.

During my test the `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` annotation is ignored and it only shows `null`.
However with e.g. Postman everything works as expected.

I using just a Spring Boot Starter with Web Starter and Test Starter dependency.

Example Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class JacksonExampleRestController {

    @PostMapping("/api")
    public void getResti(@RequestBody JacksonModel jacksonModel) {
        System.out.println(jacksonModel.getId());
        System.out.println(jacksonModel.getPassword());
    }
}

class JacksonModel {

    private String id;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        JacksonExampleRestController jacksonExampleRestController = new JacksonExampleRestController();

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(jacksonExampleRestController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testJackson() throws Exception {
        JacksonModel jacksonModel = new JacksonModel();
        jacksonModel.setId("id");
        jacksonModel.setPassword("password");

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api").
                contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(convertObjectToJsonBytes(jacksonModel)));
    }

    public static byte[] convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
    }
}
```

Is this the default behaviour and do I have to configure something in my test or is it something else I don't see right now?

Comment: Without running the code, my first instinct is to look at the fact that you are generating your JSON bytes using the object under test using Jackson. May be print out the value of what `convertObjectToJsonBytes` returns and check to see if the json string is fine?

Comment: Upon checking the method it returns only the Id. So I added `mapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false);` and it works ... Is this clean? Because it does not feel right...

Comment: I would just go ahead and just use a HashMap to generate the JSON. So, if you think about it, what you are testing is the endpoint. Whoever accesses this endpoint would not be using your model objects, so why use them in your tests? I know its convenient, but it might be safer to not use the same objects to generate requests.

Answer (score 7):

Ignoring all the annotations can be problematic. To handle a finer configuration you can implement your custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`:

```
public class IgnoreJacksonWriteOnlyAccess extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public JsonProperty.Access findPropertyAccess(Annotated m) {
        JsonProperty.Access access = super.findPropertyAccess(m);
        if (access == JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) {
            return JsonProperty.Access.AUTO;
        }
        return access;
    }
}
```

Then, after instantiating the mapper:

```
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new IgnoreJacksonWriteOnlyAccess());
```

Answer (score 1):

add the line for your ObjectMapper:

```
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with a similar setup. The problem is in the test input data. Basically, `writeValueAsBytes()` will ignore the password while serializing exactly as instructed by the annotation.

Note that, `Access.WRITE_ONLY` basically means "SetterOnly" or "DeserializationOnly" not the other way around.