# Jackson object mapper how to ignore JsonProperty annotation?

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following scenario:

```
public class A {

    @JsonProperty("member")
    private Integer Member;
}

public class B {

    private Integer Member;
}
```

Now, I wish to do the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
B b = new B(); b.setMember(1);

A a = mapper.converValue(b, A.class);
```

Ordinarily, this would work. However, since the `objectMapper` takes annotations such as `@JsonProperty` into account, I get the following result:

```
A.getMember(); // Member = NULL
```

There is a workaround, where all fields that are expected to be `null` due to this are set manually, i.e. `A.setMember(b.getMember());`, but this defeats the purpose of using the `objectMapper` in the first place and is potentially error-prone.

Is there a way to configure the `objectMapper` to ignore the `@JsonProperty` fields of a given class (or globally)?

Comment: You want Jackson to ignore the annotation that Jackson uses to ignore properties?! Something doesn't sound right...

Comment: Yes, I wish to hit myself repeatedly for having to ask this. Consequences of *RESTful naming principles*, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the ObjectMapper to ignore annotations like @JsonProperty by doing:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(
             org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false)
                .configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false)
```

But this will cause it to also ignore things like @JsonIgnore etc. I'm not aware of any way to make the ObjectMapper ignore only specific annotations.

Comment: a mix-in may work for ignoring specific annotations on a class.

Comment: It seems that this is really the only way to configure this - bummer. Since this is not a viable option, I will most likely have to resort to manual setting. I'll be accepting this nonetheless as it does answer the question.

Comment: In Jackson 2.x use `objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false)`

Answer (score 4):

To ignore *all* annotations the syntax in Jackson version 2.x is:

```
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false)
```

Just ignoring a subset seems to be not possible with this approach.

But a much better solution can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064740/3351474

For your needs it should be then:

```
public static class IgnoreJacksonPropertyName extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
  @Override
  protected <A extends Annotation> A _findAnnotation(Annotated annotated, Class<A> annoClass) {
    if (annoClass == JsonProperty.class) {
      return null;
    }
    return super._findAnnotation(annotated, annoClass);
  }
}

...

mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new IgnoreJacksonPropertyName());
```